# 'Contacts Registration Failed' Marketing Cloud Connect error

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have set up Marketing Cloud Connect and have (for now) integrated our Marketing Cloud Instance with our Salesforce Sandbox. After we have taken care of everything for configuring the Connector, when we go to Data Sources in Contact Builder, for creating Data Sources from SF objects, we get to select the Objects that we want from an available list of SF objects.

Once we have clicked on 'Synchronise' the corresponding Data Sources are created from the SF objects selected, and subsequently the Synchronised DEs are also created.

We are getting the attached error for every Data Source created. 'Contacts Registration Failed' (pic attached).[image: Errors]

Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Adam Spriggs, any ideas ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now, but unfortunately disconnecting and reconnecting didn't help in my case. Anyone else having the problem right now? Or anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently salesforce support fixes this object by object if you open a support case. The support team told me that this is due to a bug in the Contacts object which causes contact registration to fail on depending objects (and even contacts object itself). According to salesforce a bugfix will be part of the next release (**Edit:** which will be on 27th January 2017 ([Release Notes: January 2017 Release](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/january_2017_release/))).

Answer (score 0):

A weird thing happened. I was facing the same issue with our MC instance(which is integrated with our SF sandbox instance). I disconnected the integration and then reconnected it, it took some time but it seem to work now. We can edit fields now in the data sources thus created, what was required.

Any ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this means that there are 1 or more objects that are related to the object that still need to be synced.

For Contact, in your example, that would be Account.

The actual warning message doesn't mean anything, because this message also appears for objects totally unrelated to the Contact object.