# How to debug Automation Studio Audiences?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I've set up a triggered automation, that listens to csv-uploads and imports them into a data extension (using overwrite). Furthermore, I created a simple journey that uses this automation's audience as entry point. The automation runs successful and the data of the csv is correctly written to the data extension. However, the journey doesn't run for the contact in the data extension.

The email in the journey's email activity completes validation and also a test send using the data extension row inserted by the import activity succeeds.

The following info is displayed in the event results:

> **Status                                         Activity Name           Activity Type**
>
> MetCriteria                               EntryAudience         Trigger
>
> Failed                                                                       Other
>
> Complete                                                                  Other
>
> InteractionEventHandled         --                               --
>
> ContactAttempted                    --                               --

I also checked the JSON Output on the event results page, to see if there is additional information, but as far as I'm concerned it contains no useful additional information.

Comment: What Entry source data you used in entry event .

Comment: The entry source is an automation studio audience. All necessary data for the sends is correctly written to the audience's data extension via automation studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the setup of the Automation or the Journey, this was due to a bug in the Contact Schema which had to be resolved by Salesforce Support. This is related to the following question: ['Contacts Registration Failed' Marketing Cloud Connect error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/144009/36218)