# Is there a way to fix "Contacts registration failed" in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have been facing this issue since past few days, and Salesforce support takes forever to fix this although I created a ticket. I have an open priority ticket open since 3 days now.

Although from the answer shown here(['Contacts Registration Failed' Marketing Cloud Connect error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144009/contacts-registration-failed-marketing-cloud-connect-error)), it should be a standard release fix.

The issue happened because a sync which was paused  and restarted a sync.

Is there a standard way or hack to delink and sync the object again by myself?

Comment: From my experience, it needs to be done by support in the backend

Comment: Ok...maybe I have to wait for few more days